# Rust - #[serde(tag="a.x")] attribute on a sub field in JSON

Tags: json, rust, serde

I have these two structs:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct RequestBase {
    id: i32,
    method_name: String,
}


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct LoginRequest {
    base: RequestBase,

    // Login
    email: String,
    password: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct CreateAccountRequest{
    base: RequestBase,

    // Account
    email: String,
    password: String,
}
```

I want to map a json from ist "base.method_name" property.

I tried to use `#[serde(tag="base.method_name")]` but it can't access a sub property which is not in first scope.

An example of JSON:

```js
// This should map to LoginRequest struct.
{"base":{"id":1,"method_name":"LoginRequest"},"email":"a@mail.com","password":"xxxx"}

// This should map to CreateAccountRequest struct.
{"base":{"id":1,"method_name":"CreateAccountRequest"},"email":"a@mail.com","password":"xxxx"}
```

How can I do this? How can I separate `LoginRequest` and `CreateAccountRequest` (which has same fields) structs from `base.method_name`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in *serializing to* this format or *deserializing from* this format? Or both? I'm guessing its not possible with the attribute and will probably need a custom implementation. If you're in control of the JSON structure, I'd recommend differently.

Comment: I need both. I think it is not possible for now. I will just use HashMap to check with serde_json::Value["base"]["method_name"] value and map to my struct. I just wondered is there any "idiomatic rust way" to do it. :)